# Тест в Selenium сильно грузит процессор

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Вот такой код почему-то нагружает процессор, каждая новая итерация добавляет ~2% загрузки цп. Но почему? Созданное окно браузера же каждый раз закрывается. Как можно этого избежать?

```
    @Test
    public void Test() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){             
             ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();             
             driver.quit();
            }
    }
```

Comment: вам точно необходим данный цикл?

        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){             
             ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();             
             driver.quit();
            }

Comment: Да, ведь настройки вроде юзер-агента, прокси и языка пользователя нужно указать при создании экземпляра ChromeDriver, потом изменить их уже нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к `drver.quit()` [ещё пару строчек](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935535)...

```
driver.close()
driver.quit()
driver.dispose()
```

Comment: Похоже, это работает, если использовать С, но в Java у driver отсутствует метод dispose(). И driver.close() -> driver.quit() не помогает.